# Python Sleep() function disturbing my video motion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on my final year project (facemask detection) in python. I did all the things but my guide suggested attaching a common alert system to my project. so I attached the alert system. which means if anyone comes without a mask then it will alert commonly in three languages (Tamil, Hindi, English).

but it wants a separate time to run these three audios (Tamil-3sec, hindi-2sec and english-1sec). so I used sleep function `sleep()` in my program. I attached it successfully but this sleep function disturbed video motion. that's mean if I moved (with mask) and someone moved (without mask) it will show after 6sec. so it cased slow motion. I even tried multithreading concepts but I can't implement it so I want this (if anyone didn't wear facemask then it will play these audios but it won't disturb the video frame (slow motion)).

code:

````
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import voice
import threading
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
#sound=mixer.Sound('mixkit-security-facility-breach-alarm-994.wav')
alert1=mixer.Sound('Tamilalert.mp3')
alert2=mixer.Sound('Hindialert.mp3')
alert3=mixer.Sound('Englishalert.mp3')
#t2=threading.Thread(target=voice.alertsystem())
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    print(detections.shape)

    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        
            confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

            if confidence > 0.5:
                
                            
                box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

                            
                (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
                (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

                    
                face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
                face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
                face = img_to_array(face)
                face = preprocess_input(face)

            
                faces.append(face)
                locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    if len(faces) > 0:
        
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    return (locs, preds)


prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)


maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")


print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1000)

  
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)


    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        
        
          
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        
        if mask>withoutMask:
            label = "Mask"
            color = (0, 255, 0)
            print("Normal")
        else:
            label = "No Mask"
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            alert1.play()
            time.sleep(3)
            alert2.play()
            time.sleep(2)
            alert3.play()
            time.sleep(1)
            #sound.play()
            #t2=threading.Thread(target=voice.alertsystem())
            #voice.alertsystem()
            print("Alert!!!")
            
        
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

    
                   
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

  
    if key == ord("q"):
            break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()

    ```

    

    so kindly see else part of my program. and I hope you understood my problem kindly give solution
````

Comment: You were on the right lines with threading, I think you need to try making that work.  having 'sleep' in line will of course mess with any realtime processing you are trying to do.

Comment: use playsound module.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply but here the problem is sleep function each audio have to run some specific time example tamil for 3seconds so I put sleep(3) so all process cut until 3seconds so I want synchronization. but I can't able to implement multithreaded concept there

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code so u can paralyze the sleep function.

I made a helper function that I call with the threading module.

```
# helper function 
def wait(time,alert):
    alert.play()
    sleep(time)
```

.

```
# the updated for loop
for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
      
   (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
   (mask, withoutMask) = pred

    
   if mask>withoutMask:

       label = "Mask"
       color = (0, 255, 0)
       print("Normal")

   else:

       label = "No Mask"
       color = (0, 0, 255)
       Thread(target=wait, args=(3,alert1,)).start()
       Thread(target=wait, args=(2,alert2,)).start()
       Thread(target=wait, args=(1,alert3,)).start()
       #sound.play()
       #t2=threading.Thread(target=voice.alertsystem())
       #voice.alertsystem()
       print("Alert!!!")
```

**EDIT2**

This code runs the for loop and if i == 2 it starts playing the sound and then stops it after 3 seconds. But be aware of how I defined the alert. I have done it differently.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import perf_counter, sleep
import pygame
import cv2

alert = pygame.mixer
alert.init()
alert.music.load("path_to_your_mp3_file")


def wait(time, alert):
    alert.music.play()            # starts the music
    #start = perf_counter()
    sleep(time)                   # waits 3 seconds
    #print(perf_counter() - start)
    alert.stop()                  # stops the music


for i in range(10):

    if i == 2:

        Thread(target=wait, args=(3, alert,)).start()

        print("Alert")
```

Comment: No, it's not working properly. and I tried this method. That's why I mentioned I already tried multithreading concepts in my question. because sleep function isn't working in between thread. That's mean audio not played fully(Tamil not played 3sec, Hindi not played 2sec and english not played 1sec). so kindly tell any another method. I want this( if anybuddies didn't wear a mask then it play these three audios fully but it won't affect video motion)

Comment: No, it's not working. I already tried this methodology that's why I mentioned like I can't able to implement the multithreading concept in my question. sleep function didn't work properly. That means Tamil audio didn't play 3sec similarly all other audios also. so kindly give any other solution. please

Comment: sorry for the late response. Now also I facing same issues. That's mean audio didn't play fully. I implemented that loop concept also. Same problem. Sleep function duration didn't work so kindly help me to synchronize.

Comment: And the music load function didn't work it shows error in play variable.